# Not grasping CDI Injection (JSF)

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have 2 classes, LoginLookup (request scoped) and AppLogin (session scoped).  I want to generate a token only once and store the value in my AppToken instance when the LoginLookup.authenticate() method is called.  As the AppToken class is defined with session scope I assumed every time I inject an instance of this class I would get the same instance?  I was hoping I could simply use the @Inject AppToken appToken; line to grab the session scoped instance but I'm getting different instances?  I've obviously not grasped the whole CDI thing, maybe I shouldn't be using CDI at all?

Code is show below.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginLookup {
    @Inject
    private AppToken appToken;
    public String authenticate() {
        if (appToken.getToken() == null) {
            appToken.setToken(newTokenvalue);
        }
    }
}

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AppToken {
private String token;
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some more. Do you have a valid beans.xml in your META-INF folder?

Comment: How do you know you get different instances?

Comment: @Francesco the beans.xml file is present but contains only <beans></beans> not sure this is relevant tbh

Comment: @Kukeltje while debugging it is clear the appToken instances are different based on their id displayed in the Variables view (eclipse)

Comment: What 'id'??? It could be proxies... Check their **content** or check if the real instances the proxies point to are the same.

Comment: Christian, please note that for these beans CDI will create proxies (e.g. "sublasses which delegate to actual bean"). The injected proxies may differ but they should all point to the same underlaying contextual instance of your session bean for as long as you in fact have only that one session. You need to verify contents of that bean.

Comment: Sorry Kukeltje I was unawware of the proxies.  Thanks @Siliarus, I call the code appToken.setToken(...) in the LoginLookup class which updates appToken's token instance variable.  When I try and retrieve the token with appToken.getToken() I get a null value.  Back to the drawing board.  Let me double check everything! thx

Comment: How are you invoking LoginLookup.authenticate? Is it from a JSF page or from a Servlet? How do you know you even have a session? (Normally sessions are tied to a JSESSIONID cookie that the browser sends with each request)